# Fix the error with iTextSharp (PDF to text)?

Tags: c#, pdf, text, itext, extract

I am trying to recover text from PDF files with iTextSharp (NuGet) in the following way:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
string LOC_DOC = @"C:\PDF_files";

string[] PDFs = Directory.GetFiles(LOC_DOC, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (string PDF in PDFs)
    {

         PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@PDF);
             
         for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
         {
             string pageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page);
         }

    }

 this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```

The goal is simply to retrieve the contents of the PDFs, I will do the processing later.
It works fine with some PDFs but with others I have the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException : 'Impossible d'effectuer un cast d'un objet de type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfLiteral' en type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfNumber'.'
>
> System.InvalidCastException : 'Impossible to cast an objet of type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfLiteral' to type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfNumber'.'

Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: That sounds like an error in the PDF content stream; in a place where there should be a number there is something else. While PDF viewers have a tendency to try and ignore such errors, PDF processing libraries usually fail fast here. If you share an example PDF, we can analyze the issue more closely.

Comment: @mkl I can't, the 3500 PDFs are a bit sensitive. On the other hand I found the PDF which causes the same error: http://www.autosfera.lt/images/Manuals/Nussbaum/2-30-SL-manual-DE.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Analysis

The PDF you shared, [2-30-SL-manual-DE.pdf](http://www.autosfera.lt/images/Manuals/Nussbaum/2-30-SL-manual-DE.pdf), has an error in the content streams of page 6 causing the exception in that case:

```
0.1 -16 TD -3.796 Tw
[ (.)2.943 Tw ( . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .)] TJ
-0.138 -16 TD -3.796 Tw
[ (.)2.943 Tw ( . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .)] TJ
0.112 -16 TD -3.45 Tw
[ (.)3.05 Tw ( . . . . . . . . . .)] TJ
```

The **Tw**s inside the respective array arguments of the **TJ** instructions are invalid, that array may only contain strings (in round or angled brackets) and numbers, cf the specification:

> *array*
> **TJ**
> Show one or more text strings, allowing individual glyph positioning. Each element of *array* shall be either a string or a number. If the element is a string, this operator shall show the string. If it is a number, the operator shall adjust the text position by that amount.

*(ISO 32000-1, Table 109 – Text-showing operators)*

If your other documents cause the same exception (including a similar stack trace), they very likely contain such invalid non-string, non-number literals in some **TJ** instructions, too.

Thus, ask the document source to provide fixed copies of those documents.

## Work-around

In a comment you mention

> However these are old documents, it is impossible for me to request a corrected version

If the kind of content stream error discovered in the example file is the only kind of content error in your files and ignoring that extra literal always is the appropriate way to handle the error, you can wrap the `IContentOperator` processing **TJ** instructions in iText text extraction in another operator that filters the unwanted literals from the argument:

```c#
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"d:\Issues\stackoverflow\Fix the error with iTextSharp (PDF to text)\2-30-SL-manual-DE.pdf");
for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Page {0}", page);
    PdfDictionary pageDic = reader.GetPageN(page);
    PdfDictionary resourcesDic = pageDic.GetAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);
    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
    PdfContentStreamProcessor processor = new PdfContentStreamProcessor(strategy);
    TjArgumentClearingWrapper wrapper = new TjArgumentClearingWrapper();
    wrapper.WrappedOperator = processor.RegisterContentOperator("TJ", wrapper);
    processor.ProcessContent(ContentByteUtils.GetContentBytesForPage(reader, page), resourcesDic);
    string pageText = strategy.GetResultantText();
    Console.Out.WriteLine("******\n{0}\n\n", pageText);
}
```

with the helper class

```c#
class TjArgumentClearingWrapper : IContentOperator
{
    public void Invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfLiteral oper, List<PdfObject> operands)
    {
        PdfObject operand = operands[0];
        if (operand is PdfArray array)
        {
            PdfArray newArray = new PdfArray();
            foreach (PdfObject pdfObject in array)
            {
                if (pdfObject is PdfString || pdfObject is PdfNumber)
                    newArray.Add(pdfObject);
            }
            operands[0] = newArray;
        }
        WrappedOperator.Invoke(processor, oper, operands);
    }

    public IContentOperator WrappedOperator { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is probably the cause of the problem. However these are old documents, it is impossible for me to request a corrected version.

Is there any way to make iTextSharp ignore this error?

Comment: Well, of course you can change the itext code to ignore the issue somehow, it's open source after all.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to change the itext assemblies, you can copy the relevant classes for text extraction into your own namespace and change that copy.

Comment: If in case of all your problem documents the base problem is such a **TJ** instruction containing non-string, non-number literals, one can also inject a wrapper for the respective content operator which removes such literals, see the edit to my answer. Beware, though, this is an option to repair a single type (or at most a very few types) of content stream errors.

Comment: I'm an amateur, I don't understand how what you did works, let alone modify the source code but ... It works perfectly and with that I can get all the information I needed!
Thank you so much !
Your code works perfectly and is very easy to use!